# SQLite expression to count rows grouped by week

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with the only relevant column being completionDate, a number of seconds after the epoch that an item was marked complete.  I would like to do a select statement to count the number of items complete, grouped by the week in which they were marked complete.  So far, I've got something like this:

```
SELECT (completionDate-min)/(60*60*24*7)
FROM 
    (SELECT min(completionDate) AS min
     FROM TASK)
LEFT JOIN task;
```

Which returns these results:

```
0
2
2
2
3
3
3
```

Which means that 1 item was completed in the first week, and 3 items were completed in the third and 4th weeks.

I can deal with finding a better value for `min` programatically (specifically, the beginning of the week).  What I really need is a way to group by the result and count the number of results.  An ideal result would be:

```
0|1
2|3
3|3
```

My next step was to try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(idx)
FROM
    (SELECT ((completionDate-min)/(60*60*24*7)) AS idx
    FROM
         (SELECT min(completionDate) AS min
         FROM TASK)
    LEFT JOIN task)
GROUP BY idx;
```

Which gives results that look sort of kind of right, but wrong in a way I don't understand:

```
0
1
3
3
```

At this point, I'm just stuck.  I admit my SQL is not that great, so any optimization on what I have would also be appreciated.

Comment: Add "idx" to the select clause, to find the odd 0 count: SELECT idx, COUNT(idx) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT (completionDate - min) / (60*60*24*7) AS week,
       COUNT(*) AS count
FROM task, (SELECT MIN(completionDate) AS min FROM task)
GROUP BY week
HAVING completionDate NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Source of data:](http://osdir.com/ml/sqlite-users/2009-02/msg00123.html)

> SELECT strftime('%Y%W', date_col) AS w, other_data FROM my_table GROUP
>   BY w

```
See http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html for usage. That doc also
includes some caveats related to precision and locale, etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Had some null values.  Added a `WHERE completoinDate NOT NULL`:

```
SELECT idx, COUNT(idx)
FROM
    (SELECT ((completionDate-min)/(60*60*24*7)) AS idx
    FROM
         (SELECT min(completionDate) AS min
         FROM TASK)
    LEFT JOIN task WHERE completionDate NOT NULL)
GROUP BY idx;
```

Please still let me know if it can be optimized in any way.